# Why do I always get Ř instead of č? (C++, Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, visual-studio-2019, utf

> **Part 1** on encoding characters in C++ (by [User123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474063/how-to-use-operator-l-on-variable-more-exactly-array-c-visual-studio-20)).
>
> [-> Go to the next post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474063/how-to-use-operator-l-on-variable-more-exactly-array-c-visual-studio-20)

I am making an intermediate program, where I need to display some special character, which is in Czech named háček (or c with caron): č. It has [Unicode code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm) \u010D. But when I run the program, I get some other character (big R with caron, I think): Ř. I don't see exactly in the terminal.

I have read a lot of articles about UTF and Unicode. Does Visual Studio has different encoding as terminal? Is the computer confused?

My example code (but not real) is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\u010D";
}
```

I have this output:

```
Ř
```

I tried also with `printf` function, but the same result.

Is there any similarity between these two encodings?

```
        č        |       Ř
-------------------------------
   dec  |   hex  |  dec  |  hex
   269  | U+010D |  344  | U+0158
196 141 |  C4 8D |197 152| C5 98
 &#269; | &#x10D | &#344;| &#x158;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the actual code you are having trouble with.  And show the actual output you are seeing.

Comment: Try `std::wcout << L"\u010D";`;

Comment: @Paul Sanders And what does it do? I tried but there is just blank output.

Comment: `std::wcout` is Unicode aware.  `std::cout` is not.  But, the console might not handle Unicode output correctly, I'm not sure.

Comment: @PaulSanders "_`std::wcout` is Unicode aware_" is a bit rich. It does not translate unicode into the specific encoding you wish to have. UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 does not work out of the box with `wcout` on Windows. Perhaps `wcout` and UTF-32 works elsewhere, but not on Windows. `UTF-16LE` (or whatever it's narrowed down to is called) works reasonably well on Windows but nowhere else.

Comment: I get `č` on my machine here which is properly UTF-8 in the terminal. Maybe your terminal *isn't* UTF-8, but some other encoding. To narrow this down, try a series of characters, not just that one, to see if there's any pattern to the mismatches.