# How to use operator L on array? (C++, Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, visual-studio-2019

> **Part 2** on encoding characters in C++ (by [User123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106320/user123)).
>
> [<- Go to the previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469861/why-do-i-always-get-%C5%98-instead-of-%C4%8D-c-visual-studio)

I was yesterday making some code, and [Paul Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743288/paul-sanders) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469861/why-do-i-always-get-%C5%98-instead-of-%C4%8D-c-visual-studio) told me useful solution: He told me not to use `std::cout << "something";` but to use `std::wcout << L"something";`.

But I have another problem. Now I want to do something like this (some special characters, but in array):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string myArray[2] = { "łŁšđřžőšě", "×÷¤ßł§ř~ú" };
int main()
{
    cout << myArray[0] << endl << myArray[1];
    return 0;
}
```

But now I get something really unusual:

```
│úÜ­°×§Üý
Î¸Ą▀│ž°~˙
```

If I add `L` in front of the array, I get (Visual Studio 2019):

```
C++ initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object
```

How can I represent these special characters but in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
wstring myArray[2] = { L"łŁšđřžőšě", L"×÷¤ßł§ř~ú" };
int main()
{
    wcout << myArray[0] << endl << myArray[1];
    return 0;
}
```

`L` can only be applied directly to string literals. The result is a string literal of type `wchar_t[]` (*wide* character) rather then the usual `char_t[]` (*narrow* character), so you cannot save it in a `string`. You need to save it in a `wstring`. And to output a `wstring` you need to pass it to `wcout`, not `cout`.

Comment: Doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019, Windows 7 Professional. There aren't any characters at all, just blank output.

Comment: @User123 But you are saying that `std::wcout << L"łŁšđřžőšě";` or something similar works?

Comment: Yes, but I need to specify ```#include <fcntl.h>#include <io.h>``` and then ```_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);```.

Comment: @User123 Then do the same for this example and it should work. The details of how wide characters behave is implementation-defined.

Comment: I have a small problem: Data (array) is written in another file than main.cpp.

Comment: And how can I accept such special characters in wchar_t?

Comment: @User123 I don't see what the problem is. You do the setup with `#include <fcntl.h>#include <io.h>` and `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` in `main` and then you can use wide character versions of all string-related tools as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the error, but now I can't accept special characters in ```wstring x; cin >> x;```. I get the error. C++ no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::istream >> std::wstring

Comment: @User123 Use `wcin` instead of `cin`.